# How to style the foreground of SVG paths used as cytoscape.js nodes?

Tags: svg, foreground, cytoscape.js

How can I set the foreground color of an SVG element used as a node in cytoscape.js?

I'm familiar with setting id's for SVG path elements in the DOM and then using CSS to style them.  Is something similar possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I was really looking for is a way to have scalable SVG node icons that can be colored dynamically to indicate app-defined status of the node.  I didn't want to statically create all the possible colored variants ahead of time.  In the end, I used svg.js to dynamically apply styles to SVG icons that are used for nodes (actually for node backgrounds), then convert it to base64 for the data url to pass to cytoscape.js as the background svg.

Comment: Could you please  post an example ?

Comment: Can you post an example, please?

Answer (score 1):

Cytoscape JS uses `<canvas>` tags to render the nodes and edges rather than SVG. It's not terribly obvious in their documentation, but there is a passing [reference](http://js.cytoscape.org/#performance/background).

To style the nodes and edges, you use [their own styling system](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style).  It is inspired by CSS, but is not *actual* CSS.